# Convert vector<int8> to vector<uint8>

Tags: c++, c++17

I am consuming an api that returns a byte array as `std::vector<int8>`, but the rest of my application consumes byte arrays as `std::vector<uint8>`.

How can I convert `std::vector<int8>` to `std::vector<uint8>`?

Comment: Does [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1953708/1424875) offer a suitable starting point for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the constructor that accepts a range of iterators:

```
std::vector<uint8>(std::begin(signed_vec), std::end(signed_vec));
```

That said, in case you don't actually need a `std::vector<uint8>` object, but rather simply want to read a range of unsigned integers, you can reinterpret them instead:

```
uint8* ptr_beg = reinterpret_cast<uint8>(signed_vec.data());
uint8* ptr_end = ptr_beg + signed_vec.size();
```

Conversion between unsigned and signed versions of the same integer size is one of the rare cases where reinterpretation is well defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse through each element and cast/push back to the new vector:

```
std::vector<int8> vec_int8 = returnedFromApi(); // assume it is filled
std::vector<uint8> vect_uint8;
for(int item = 0; item < vec_int8.size(); ++item)
{
  vect_uint8.push_back(static_cast<uint8>(vec_int8[item]));
}
```